# centering contents of topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft and bottomRight ids

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive site (resize the browser window to see the changes), but I'm unable to center these checkered divs.

http://arunmahendrakar.com/ktw/play.html

The divs are dynamically created and appended to one of the four 'container' divs (#topLeft, #topRight, #bottomLeft and #bottomRight).

I have tried using margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto on various elements, but that did not help.

Please help me horizontally center the #topLeft, #topRight, #bottomLeft and #bottomRight divs. I prefer a pure CSS solution, but if it is not do-able, I'm ok with a js tweak as well.

Comment: Just to confirm, you wish each checkerboard to be centered in it's respective container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of different way to do this with some tweaking to the way you build that structure.  Here's what I'd do:

First, size things a bit more normally; make the quadrants (`#topLeft` for example) `width: 100%` and the individual square sizes `padding: 5%`.  This will give the squares the same size as they have currently, but the 100% width ensures that things are actually centered where you want them to be.  At 200% the "center" of a quadrant will be off by 50%.

Next, instead of using `float` and `clear`, use `display: inline-block` on the squares.  This will have them all running together on a line; your Javascript can manually break them up by inserting a `<br>` after every 5 squares.  You'll no longer need to add the `clearBoth` class once you've done this.

At this point, you should have almost exactly what you want.  There will, however, be some extra spacing between each row of squares.  This is due to whitespace in the HTML, and to get rid of it, just set make sure the quadrants (again, `#topLeft` for example) have `font-size: 0` set.

That ought to do it!

**Explanation**

It's really pretty simple: `display: inline-block` obeys text align.  By creating your checkerboards out of `inline-block` elements instead of floats, you can control which side they align to by just changing out `text-align`.

All the other stuff is just some necessary cleanup work to make this technique work nicely.

Comment: You must be a genius! Just those quick changes and viola... it worked like a charm. Many thanks to you.